# Get the pagename of the URL

Tags: cakephp-1.3

I have a url like this: http://www.sample.com/widget/mywidget/

How can I get only the "mywidget" in the url?

Answer (score 0):

Try `debug($this->params)` inside your controller and have a look at what's available inside the array.

You will find a number of URL parts inside that property, including the `'action'` key, which I think is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the code below:

```
echo $this->params->pass['1']
```

Comment: For better readability please edit your post and format your code as code (just select the code and click the "code" button, that looks like this: `{}`).